# android google maps v2: resize polygon

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to draw polygon on google maps which may be resized. Any marker removed successfully by onMarkerClick but I can't change marker position by drag it to another place.
Here is my code:

```
        PolygonOptions polygon = new PolygonOptions(); 
        Polygon my_polygon ;
        polygon.fillColor(Color.RED);
....
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
    my_polygon.remove();
    arg0.remove();
    polygon.getPoints().remove(arg0.getPosition()); //it's ok, marker deleted

    return true;
}

 @Override
  public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker)
  {  
      polygon.getPoints().remove(marker.getPosition()); //marker still in polygon list

  }
  @Override
  public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker)
  {  

  polygon.getPoints().remove(marker.getPosition());  //marker still in polygon list


  }
  @Override
  public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker)
  {  
      my_polygon.remove(); 
      polygon.getPoints().remove(marker.getPosition());  //marker still in polygon list
    polygon.add(marker.getPosition());
  my_polygon=map.addPolygon(polygon); //created new polygon which contains previous marker position
  }
```

So, how can I remove previus marker points correctly?

Comment: at begin you say that you remove the markers correctly. At the end you ask how to remove marker correctly. What am i missing here?!

Answer (score 0):

First keep all the LatLng points in a arraylist of LatLng.
Dont remove marker in 
     **onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker)**  even save it to a new LatLng variable. Now at **onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker)** , first get the new point and then remove the old one that u were save in the new LatLng variable . At the same time you need to remove the same marker from the arraylist that u have saved and add this new value and then draw a polygon again.

for example if suppose u have declare an arraylist of latlng like this 
     ArrayList points = new ArrayList();

then draw a ploygon in  **onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker)** like the following

```
Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
        .addAll(points)
        .strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
        .strokeWidth(5)
        .fillColor(0x884d4d4d));
```

try this. hope it will help. :)

Comment: It didn't help. Seems like at OnMarkerDragStart I've got already changed coordinates.